# como inicializar o id da venda na classe de impressão?

Tags: java, html, xhtml, jasper

Gostaria de receber o id da `venda` na classe de impressão da pagina, sendo que ele vem nulo, e estou usando ele para comparar com o `idvenda` com o parâmetro criado no jasper.

impressao.html

```
      <p:commandLink  title="Imprimir" action="#{relatorioMB.emitir}" ajax="false" target="_blank" >
          <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir teste 
          <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{vendaMB.venda}" value="#{lin}" />
     </p:commandLink>
```

Usei `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{vendaMB.venda}" value="#{lin}" />`, mas só funciona em `vendaMB`.

ImpressaoRelatorio.java

```
     private Venda venda;  parametros.put("idvenda", venda.getIdvenda());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável venda do MB VendaMB precisa estar com anotada com @ViewScoped.

Para capturar no MB ImpressaoMB injete o VendaMB.

Na ImpressaoMB ficaria assim:

```
@Inject
private VendaMB vendaMB;

public meuMetodo(){
  this.vendaMB.getVenda().getId();
}
```

Comment: muito bom, só esqueci de falar que uso outra classe filha de impressaoMB, e onde é pra ser usado o `this.vendaMB.getVenda().getIdvenda();`

Comment: e como faço quando é outra classe sem ser BEAN?

Comment: poderia especificar melhor seu cenário?